# Need to select specific element except its one of the descendant

Tags: xslt

In my xml,

```
<section level="2">
    <heading class="hdgautonum2" level="2">
        <inline style="\-ilx-tab-stops: left blank 0tw; ">
            <gentext type="headingnumberstring">1.5  </gentext>
            <deleted author="Michele Staple" date="Wed, 17 Aug 2011 18:18:00 BST">Overview</deleted>
            <inserted author="Michele Staple" date="Wed, 17 Aug 2011 18:18:00 BST">Chapter summary</inserted>
        </inline>
    </heading>
...
</section>
```

and, in my xslt,

```
<xsl:for-each select="child::section[@level='2']">
<xsl:variable name="subsecHead" select="if (heading//inserted) then (heading//*[not(name()='deleted')]) else heading"/>
```

note: i do not need `deleted` to the output, so, i made that exceptional (i mean not())

but, i have this error

> XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
>     substring() ("1.5 OverviewChapter summary", "1.5", ...)

My aim is to select the `heading` element and its all descendants except `deleted` element content if the heading element does have `inserted`. Else, it is just to select `heading` element only. Sometimes, heading element does have `inserted` element or may not be..

Am I making sense?

Comment: There's no use of the `substring` function in the snippet you've supplied.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: The error points to a substring function but you don't show one in your XSLT. Can you update your question to show more of the XML and XSLT?

Comment: Hi: I have edited my question, please have a look

Comment: Er, no, you're not exactly "making sense". There is still no use of `substring`. If you are unwilling to show where you use it, we cannot help you.

Comment: @muller: I have not used any substring, it is the error that i am getting when running the script

Comment: This makes even less sense. You get this error only if you make use of the `substring()` function in your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more code? It's not productive to try to help with the insufficient information you posted.

Answer (score 0):

well, this is a shot in the dark. You could replace

```
<xsl:variable name="subsecHead" select="if (heading//inserted) then (heading//*[not(name()='deleted')]) else heading"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:variable name="subsecHead" select="if (heading//inserted) then (heading//* except descendant::deleted) else heading"/>
```

use XSL 2.0

Comment: @Lamsen: I am getting the same error. i am using xslt 2.0 only. I tried this already.

Comment: Then find the substring that causes the error. I'm pretty sure that the error was not in the above code.